How to configure enumitem such that lists look like indented paragraphs?
How can I configure enumitem such that lists look like this:

Preceeding text.
    (1) First item consisting of some text consisting of 
at least two lines.
    (2) Second item indented.

Further text.


What have you tried so far? (it is good practice here to provide an example that others can copy and play with as is)

For a curious coincidence, a friend asked me about the same problem a few minutes ago!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-3]

\begin{enumerate}[
  leftmargin=0pt,
  noitemsep,
  align=left,
  labelwidth=0pt,
  itemindent=\dimeval{\parindent+\labelsep},
  label=(\arabic*),
]
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Of course, it's better if you define your own list environment from this.

your friend in real life may not trust you so much if they came here imemdiately to ask on this site from real experts on the web ;-)

By use of the wide option:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}[wide,
                  align=left,
                  label=(\arabic*),
                ]
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \lipsum[2][1-3]
\item \lipsum[3][1-3]
\item \lipsum[4][1-3]
\item \lipsum[5][1-3]
\item \lipsum[6][1-3]
\item \lipsum[7][1-3]
\item \lipsum[8][1-3]
\item \lipsum[9][1-3]
\item \lipsum[10][1-3]
\item \lipsum[11][1-3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


